# Package.appxmanifest not present in solution

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, blend

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I've started my Windows Phone 8 app in Blend, and finished it in Visual studio.
According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br230259.aspx), I need to:

> 1. In Visual Studio, close the manifest file if it’s already open in XML code view.
> 2. In Solution Explorer, expand the project node of the app.
> 3. Double-click the Package.appxmanifest file.

The problem is - I don't have Package.appxmanifest file in my solution. How to create it? Maybe I need to convert my solution to windows store project? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked in the Properties node in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I've searched it using solution explorer search box, and nothing found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in Windows Phone application there is WMAppManifest.xml file instead of Package.appxmanifest.

Answer (score 3):

That's poorly worded documentation.  As Windows Phone 8 projects do not contain a Package.appxmanifest--they contain WMAppManifest.xml which you can edit in a "designer".  I've tried upgrading a WP 8 project to 8.1 and it in fact adds an Package.appxmanifest--which is editable in a "designer".  I'm surmising that if you also added a Windows Store app to your solution, converting it to a Universal app, it would do the same thing.